# Getting "gocql: no response to connection startup within timeout" while connecting to Cassandra

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

Trying to connect to Cassandra (v 3.10.0) using gocql (Go: 1.8.3). Here is the error

***gocql: unable to dial control conn [hostIP]: gocql: no response to connection startup within timeout***

***panic: gocql: unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: gocql: no response to connection startup within timeout***

here is the code...

```
func test() {
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("hostIP")
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 4
    cluster.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{
        Username: "<username>",
        Password: "<password>",
    }
    cluster.Keyspace = "myspace"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.One
    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
}
```

Can anyone point to what i could be missing ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok.. this is resolved. Posting in case this ends up helping someone

the first error was resolved by using `ConnectTimeout` i.e. `cluster.ConnectTimeout = time.Second * 10`

then i got this error (found using `gocql_debug`) - `unable to dial "<internal VM IP>": dial tcp <internal VM IP>:9042: i/o timeout` (more [here](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues/1020))

and i resolved it by setting `cluster.DisableInitialHostLookup` to true